# tar uncompressing giving errors

Tags: solaris, tar

I have the following command in a script. $1 is a tar.gz file. It is being deployed on a Solaris OS

```
gunzip < $1 | tar -verbose xf –
```

This has worked in the past, but the tar was about half as big as it is now. Not sure if that would matter.
I am getting the following error:

```
tar: invalid blocksize "xf".
```

I have scoured the internet and SO with no luck.
Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Comment: `tar -verbose` isn't valid on any variation of `tar` that I've ever encountered.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `tar xvf`?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what version of tar your are running too.  If you have [gtar](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/gtar/) installed you can use this command

`/usr/local/bin/tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz`

or if you have GNU tar installed please try this one

`tar xzf archive.tar.gz -C /destination`

If these options didn't work, please let me know which Solaris version you are running?